# Apply content organizer rules everytime a document is updated

Tags: office-365, content-organizer

In a sharepoint site we have activated Content Organizer feature. When a document is uploaded, content organizer check a custom property of the document metadata and redirect the document to an appropiate library based on a set of rules.

What we want is that if a user with edit permissions update this document property, content organizer check again the rules and redirect the document to a new library if it is necessary.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and say "no".

Here's an interesting article that agrees.

> In certain scenarios you would like to be able to re-submit documents
>   when certain metadata of that document is changed. Out of the box this
>   isn’t possible this means you will have to create a custom solution.

http://msftplayground.com/2011/02/re-submitting-files-with-the-content-organizer-submitting-files-through-code/

Comment: Thank you Tiago. I don't think it is possible. I am trying to send the file again to the dropoff library with a workflow amd see if it is rerouted. Thank you anyway.

Comment: so I answered your question? :)

Comment: Yes. I thought I already accepted it :)